# What is the meaning and how to get the sourceUri and destinationUri in uCrop Library by Yalantis?

Tags: android, uri, crop, ucrop

I am creating an Image Cropper Activity. However, my app is not working. I do not know what is the sourceUri and destinationUri means in the builder pattern of the uCrop Library by Yalantis. How can we get or find the sourceUri and destinationUri?

I noticed the contributor in Github said that destinationUri is " where you store the Uri. But how can we get the location to store it? For the sourceUri, I getIntent from another activity to get the imageUri.

I get the imageUri from another activity and I make it as the sourceUri. Please kindly correct me and my mistakes. Thank you very much.

```
File tempFile = new File (String.valueOf(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ImageUri")));
File tempCropped = new File(getCacheDir(),"tempImgCropped.png");
Uri sourceUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(tempCropped);


UCrop.of(sourceUri,destinationUri)
    //.withAspectRatio(1,1)
    //.withMaxResultSize(40,40)
      .start(this);
```

I hope that I can get to know what is the meaning of sourceUri and destinationUri and how to get those Uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we get or find the sourceUri and destinationUri?

The sourceUri as you mentionned is retrieved through your `Intent`'s extras, and it represents the `PATH` to the image that you are working on.

The destinationUri means the `PATH` where you want to save your cropped image. It can be on the external storage or anywhere you decide to.

Comment: If this answers your question consider accepting it so others can benefit from it.